# Converting boost::asio::ip::address_v4::bytes_type into boost::asio::ip::address_v4

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to convert array of bytes of type `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::bytes_type` into `boost::asio::ip::address_v4`.

So my question is there any embedded function in boost library that do this job, or I need to do it manually i.e. Convert the array into string IP address and then pass it to the constructor of address_v4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the constructor that takes a `bytes_types`? `explicit address_v4(const bytes_type & bytes);`

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/address_v4.html

Comment: @sehe Actually I just grabbed the link to the first hit back from google that had the constructor in question. The page names are easily modified to a user's specific version of boost.